How to create an USB flash drive that can run Powershell?
I need to create an USB flash drive specifically for loading OS images in new computers with DISM.
And I would like to be able to run PowerShell scripts from that boot drive, because I can have more control over the system and extract more information before install the images.
How can I do that?

My company's infra department uses and old AOMEI Partition Tools with CMD.exe that doesn't even have findstr.exe and other tools, and I can't even run a decent batch script.

If you want to use powershell in the windowsPE stage during windows setup you should be able to add it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-adding-powershell-support-to-windows-pe?view=windows-11

@NickSlash can you type this as an answer here?

Use WindowsToGo. You make one USB media bootable with it and you can freely operate then.
You can make such disk/pendrive with Rufus:
https://rufus.ie/

@NaN you won't be able to run PowerShell outside Windows. Maybe some Linux packages with .NET would allow you to do that, but there is dedicated Linux PowerShell for that.

Will this Windows pendrive work on different computers or will it crash?

@NaN well... This is hazardous, as it may work and may not. Depends on the drivers installed and PC hardware.

Is "WindowsToGo" an option of Rufus, Windows or something else?

@A.L: A feature of Windows, but Windows' own setup tool (for ToGo) is very restrictive; Rufus allows ordinary people to set up a WindowsToGo disk painlessly.

@BenVoigt Is there a documentation about it? This article says that it has been removed. '"Windows To Go is removed in Windows 10, version 2004 and later operating systems." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-10/deployment/windows-to-go/windows-to-go-overview

@A.L: Just one of many details that you have to worry about yourself if you aren't using a tool like Rufus.

If you want to use Powershell during the windows PE stage of setup you can add it.
Please read the following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-adding-powershell-support-to-windows-pe?view=windows-11
What follows is a quick and dirty copy paste from that article.
this will create a custom windows pe environment with powershell.
dism is available without adding anything extra so can be used to deploy images.
again, please read the article/documentation above.
Prerequisites: Windows ADK and Windows PE Add-On for the ADK
The following is specifically for amd64 and en-us
Launch the "Deployment and Imaging Tools Environment" (Start Menu>Windows Kits) as Administrator.
The following commands should be run from this prompt.
create a copy of the windows PE files
copype amd64 "C:\WinPE_amd64"

mount the boot image
dism /mount-image /imagefile:"C:\WinPE_amd64\media\sources\boot.wim" /index:1 /mountdir:"C:\WinPE_amd64\mount"

add the additional components required to run powershell
dism /add-package /image:"C:\WinPE_amd64\mount" /packagepath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Windows Preinstallation Environment\amd64\WinPE_OCs\WinPE-WMI.cab"
dism /add-package /image:"C:\WinPE_amd64\mount" /packagepath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Windows Preinstallation Environment\amd64\WinPE_OCs\en-us\WinPE-WMI_en-us.cab"
dism /add-package /image:"C:\WinPE_amd64\mount" /packagepath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Windows Preinstallation Environment\amd64\WinPE_OCs\WinPE-NetFX.cab"
dism /add-package /image:"C:\WinPE_amd64\mount" /packagepath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Windows Preinstallation Environment\amd64\WinPE_OCs\en-us\WinPE-NetFX_en-us.cab"
dism /add-package /image:"C:\WinPE_amd64\mount" /packagepath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Windows Preinstallation Environment\amd64\WinPE_OCs\WinPE-Scripting.cab"
dism /add-package /image:"C:\WinPE_amd64\mount" /packagepath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Windows Preinstallation Environment\amd64\WinPE_OCs\en-us\WinPE-Scripting_en-us.cab"
dism /add-package /image:"C:\WinPE_amd64\mount" /packagepath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Windows Preinstallation Environment\amd64\WinPE_OCs\WinPE-PowerShell.cab"
dism /add-package /image:"C:\WinPE_amd64\mount" /packagepath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Windows Preinstallation Environment\amd64\WinPE_OCs\en-us\WinPE-PowerShell_en-us.cab"
dism /add-package /image:"C:\WinPE_amd64\mount" /packagepath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Windows Preinstallation Environment\amd64\WinPE_OCs\WinPE-StorageWMI.cab"
dism /add-package /image:"C:\WinPE_amd64\mount" /packagepath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Windows Preinstallation Environment\amd64\WinPE_OCs\en-us\WinPE-StorageWMI_en-us.cab"
dism /add-package /image:"C:\WinPE_amd64\mount" /packagepath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Windows Preinstallation Environment\amd64\WinPE_OCs\WinPE-DismCmdlets.cab"
dism /add-package /image:"C:\WinPE_amd64\mount" /packagepath:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Assessment and Deployment Kit\Windows Preinstallation Environment\amd64\WinPE_OCs\en-us\WinPE-DismCmdlets_en-us.cab"

commit the changes to the image
dism /unmount-image /mountdir:"C:\WinPE_amd64\mount" /commit

create a bootable usb drive with your image (where z: is your usb drive)
makewinpemedia /ufd "C:\WinPE_amd64" z:

booting from this usb drive should launch to a command prompt, where you are able to then launch powershell
